# Multithreading Java - Joins

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I am new to multithreading in java and would like to confirm that the following code works as I think it does.

```
        // Inside class Menu
        for (User user : users)
        {
            UserThread uT = new UserThread(user);
            uT.start();
            try
            {
                uT.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

So for each user inside an arraylist called users, a new thread is created and started. Then `uT.Join()` is used to tell the Menu class to wait for the threads to finish before it can continue. Is that correct?

The multithreading works successfully without `uT.Join()` however the Menu class will display a menu and it will clash with the other threads that also print out something. Also without the join, the threads don't always print out in the same order, but when using join, they always seem to print in the same order, which is what is worrying me.

What I am unsure of is, does `uT.Join()` only ask the main thread that displays the menu to wait or does it also ask the other user threads to wait? I want my threads to be concurrent and not to obstruct each other in any way.

PS: I do realise there are multiple topics about this question and I apologise for adding another to the collection, but I was unable to find one that I could perfectly understand.

Thanks for reading, if I have missed any information that should be added please don't hesitate to inform me.

Comment: `uT.join()` waits until the `uT` thread has terminated.  It has no effect on the uT thread or on any other thread except the one in which it is called.

Comment: Your loop starts one thread, and then waits for it to terminate before starting the next thread.  If you want the threads to run in parallel, then you're going to need two loops.  The first loop should start the threads and add them to a `List<Thread>`.  The second loop should then `join()` each of the threads in the list.

Comment: Also, note that a _class_ doesn't wait on threads -- only a _thread_ waits on threads. The class is just some metadata floating around in the conceptual either, "this is what a Menu is."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you designed the code is wrong. Using `Thread#join` will stop the execution of the current thread until the thead being executed finishes.

This is how the code should be designed:

```
List<UserThread> userThreadList = new ArrayList<UserThread>();
for (User user : users) {
    UserThread uT = new UserThread(user);
    uT.start();
    userThreadList.add(uT);
}

for (UserThread uT : userThreadList) {
    try
    {
        uT.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Note that it will be better to use `ExecutorService` for these tasks rather than trying to implement it manually.

Comment: Thank you so much Luiggi! It works just as I wanted it to work. I appreciate your help and I know now a little bit more about multithreading and how I should go about handling multiple threads. I will also take your advice and look at the ExecutorService for my next program. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite, since your join is in the same loop as the the start, it will wait for the thread to finish before starting the next one.

You'd need two loops to accomplish that. One to start the threads and store them in some collection, and another loop to iterate through the collection and join each thread.

Comment: Or use a `ExecutorService`